# RDMA over native Infiniband

Tags: infiniband, rdma

Is it possible to use RDMA over native InfiniBand without  IPoIB (using just guid or lid)?

I have checked [Infiniband addressing - host names to IB address without IBoIP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753332/infiniband-addressing-host-names-to-ib-address-without-iboip) and in RDMA Connection Manager source files to create connection between ports without IPoIB, but unfortunately was unable to find how to do this.

Comment: Try to ask in Mellanox community.
First try to find existing answer, e.g. https://community.mellanox.com/s/article/howto-enable--verify-and-troubleshoot-rdma

Comment: I did not find anything on topic in Mellanox community as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use librdmacm to create connections with the `AF_IB` address family and use native InfiniBand GIDs to communicate, even without setting IPoIB.

There's an example code that uses AF_IB (among other examples) in the [cmatose.c](https://github.com/linux-rdma/rdma-core/blob/master/librdmacm/examples/cmatose.c) example program in librdmacm.